# How to apply an affine transformation (4x4 matrix) to ndgrid/meshgrid results?

Tags: matlab, matrix, geometry, affinetransform

`M` is an affine transformation matrix that can transform coordinates from one coordinate system to another as follows:

```
v_old = [ x_old y_old z_old 1];
v_new = M * v_old;
% v_new contains [ x_new y_new z_new 1 ]
```

Now, I've got coordinates on the form of ndgrid/meshgrid:

```
[ X_old Y_old Z_old ] = ndgrid( 0:15 ); % for instance
```

How can I convert these to `X_new` etc?

I could do it with three for-loops loop (`X_old(i,j,k)` corresponds to `x_old` above) but there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to rearrange the values so that each point has its four coordinates in one row:

```
result = [X_old(:) Y_old(:) Z_old(:) ones(numel(X_old),1)] * M;
```

Each row of `result` gives the new coordinates of each point.

Note that this works because multiplying matrix `A` times matrix `B` is the same as multiplying each row of `A` times `B`.

Or, if you can't afford to build the above matrix (because of memory limitations), use

```
result = X_old(:)*M(1,:) + Y_old(:)*M(2,:) + Z_old(:)*M(3,:) + ones(numel(X_old),1)*M(4,:);
```

In either case, if you want to rearrange the result so that it has the same size as `X_old`, `Y_old`, `Z_old`, use this as a last step:

```
s = size(X_old);
X_new = reshape(result(:,1), s);
Y_new = reshape(result(:,2), s);
Z_new = reshape(result(:,3), s);
```

Comment: Neat! I've got a very large matrix, though (X_old is 512x512x300), so I can't afford to create that matrix while I've still got the ndgrid results.

Comment: ("afford" as in "keep in RAM")

Comment: @Anna In that case you might need a loop that builds each row of the matrix: `result(ii,:) = [X_old(ii) Y_old(ii) Z_old(ii) 1] * M;` where `ii` is the loop variable (from `1` to `numel(X)`). Or build the matrix in chunks, using as many rows per chunk as you can afford

Comment: @Anna I think I found a way. Please see updated answer

Comment: Thanks. I tried your update though, but the results are not the same as with the other method. The fourth column isn't even all ones.

Comment: Ah, `M` must be transposed. Thank you!